# How can I count when I get my data from two column?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have got 2 tables in SQL.

```
hfm_files =>  id, user_id, etc...
downloaded => id, hfm_file_id, etc...
```

And I know my `user id`. How can I count how many download was for one file with simple SQL?
I tried to make some query, but I cant make it:

```
UPDATE user u
SET u.affilite_pont = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downloaded vm WHERE
```

Comment: How are both tables linked? (which field?)

Comment: What is the relation between these tables?

Comment: The only same column is hfm_files `ID` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get count by joining both tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(d.ID) 
  FROM downloaded d
  JOIN hfm_files h
    ON d.hfm_file_id = h.id
 WHERE h.user_id = 1;
```

So you update query should be:

```
UPDATE user u
SET u.affilite_pont = (
                        SELECT COUNT(d.ID) 
                          FROM downloaded d
                          JOIN hfm_files h
                            ON d.hfm_file_id = h.id
                         WHERE h.user_id = 1;
                      )
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id) FROM 
downloaded t1, hfm_files t2 
WHERE t2.id = t1.hfm_file_id 
AND t2.user_id = <user_id>
```